# How to add button on each slide of carousel slider

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have been using flutter and the carousel slider package to create an image slider of 3 images
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
However, i want to add a button on each of those sliders on top of the images as you would see in e-commerce apps for example to "shop now" the sale etc.
like so:
[image]

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final featuredImages = [
    'lib/assets/images/elitefeatured.jpg',
    'lib/assets/images/guabafeatured.jpg',
    'lib/assets/images/eliteclubfeatured.jpg'
  ]; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { //extra non-relevant code in here

 Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 85,
                    ),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 450,
                      height: 300,
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          autoPlay: true,
                        ),
                        items: featuredImages.map((featuredImage) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7),
                            child: Image.asset(featuredImage),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
}
```

Comment: Wrap your `CarouselSlider` with a `Stack`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?
How would i add a different button for each image

Comment: No, you don't need to add button for each image , `CarouselSlider`  widget will be present in `Stack` and `Stack` has 3 widgets , 2 arrows for each side and a slider

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 important ideas:

1. Use a `Stack` widget to display your right and left arrows
2. Use a `CarouselController` to programmatically control your carousel

In code:

```dart
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  /// Create a controller to control the carousel programmatically
  CarouselController carouselController = CarouselController();

  final featuredImages = [
    'lib/assets/images/elitefeatured.jpg',
    'lib/assets/images/guabafeatured.jpg',
    'lib/assets/images/eliteclubfeatured.jpg'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //extra non-relevant code in here

    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 85,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
              carouselController: carouselController, // Give the controller
              options: CarouselOptions(
                autoPlay: true,
              ),
              items: featuredImages.map((featuredImage) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7),
                  child: Image.asset(featuredImage),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Use the controller to change the current page
                  carouselController.previousPage();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Use the controller to change the current page
                  carouselController.nextPage();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added factor to previous to move the icon down

```
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          heightFactor: 7.7,
```

and added logic to display the icons only if there is move items

```
            if(maxImageIndex>0 && feedProvider.currentImageIndex > 0) Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              heightFactor: 7.7,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Use the controller to change the current page
                  buttonCarouselController.previousPage();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.grey,),
              ),
            ),//left


            onPageChanged: (value, read) {
              setState(() {
                feedProvider.currentImageIndex = value;
              });
            },
```